# Am I using the semi-colon in this paragraph correctly?

Tags: semicolons

I'm writing a short intro for my portfolio. Am I using the semi-colon in the right place, and does it make sense?

> Hey, I'm Andy. A 25 year old designer and developer; creator of eye
>   catching designs and developer of smart web app solutions.

Comment: Your second sentence doesn't have a verb in it. Given that the sentence consists of three parallel elements—"A 25 year old designer and developer," "[a] creator of eye catching designs," and "[a] developer of smart web app solutions"—I don't see why you'd want to put a semicolon-strength break between the first  element and the other two; a comma would do a better job of guiding the reader to see the continuity of the presentation, in my opinion. Also, as a matter of style, I would hyphenate "25-year-old" and eye-catching" as compound adjectives.

Comment: I'd use a dash here (far less hifalutin than the (here) equivalent colon): 'Hey, I'm Andy – a 25-year-old designer and developer,  creator of eye-catching designs, and developer of smart web app solutions.'

Answer (score 1):

semicolon is used to join two or more ideas (parts) in a sentence, those ideas are then given equal position or rank.

"Some people write with a word processor; others write with a pen or pencil."

Semicolon between two independent clauses that are connected by conjunctive adverbs or transitional phrases.

"But however they choose to write, people are allowed to make their own decisions; as a result, many people swear by their writing methods."

Avoid using a comma when a semicolon is needed:
This example is not correct in terms of academic English punctuation: "The cow is brown, it is also old."
Correct: "The cow is brown; it is also old."

https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html

Comment: See, because I was explaining the Design and Development side of my previous statement, I thought semi-colon was correct. WHat's the best way to write the paragraph?